# Extract object state from spring task running at regular intervals

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I schedule a Spring task scheduler implementation that fetches list of updated value objects from the database. So each time the task is invoked, it is responsible for fetching the delta objects. The task is run every 10 minutes or so. The output of the task runner is used to run a custom Hadoop job. The task is initialized via annotations so I am not programmatically explicitly triggering the task.

My XML configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">       
   <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bofa.ecom.search.scheduler" />
    <bean id="configurationScheduler" class="com.bofa.ecom.search.scheduler.ConfigurationScheduler" scope="prototype"/>
    <task:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
      <task:scheduled ref="configurationScheduler" method="refreshConfiguration" fixed-rate="5000" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
</beans>
```

My scheduler interface

```
package testing;

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;

    public interface IConfigurationScheduler extends DisposableBean {

      void refreshConfiguration();

      Configuration getConfiguration();

    }

Concrete implementation

package testing;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ConfigurationScheduler implements IConfigurationScheduler {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

  @Override
  public Configuration getConfiguration() {
    return this.configuration;
  }

  /**
   * The implementation is responsible for executing the following tasks.
   * @return
   */
  // Refresh every 5 seconds after a 2 second delay.
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay=2000)
  @Async
  @Override
  public void refreshConfiguration() {
    // Fetch the data from the database and create a map of configuration metadata.
   // Iterate through map key set and invoke Configuration#set(String, String) within 
   // the loop.
   // **HOW DO I ACCESS THE CONFIGURATION OBJECT?**
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() throws Exception {
    this.configuration.clear();
  }
}
```

In my main method, I do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("test");
    ApplicationContext unusedContext =
          new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("C:\\Users\\karkuma\\workspace\\test\\src\\conf\\scheduler-conf.xml");

  }
```

My problem

1. Scheduler is triggered as soon as I initialize the application context. The main method has no way to access the task runner instance. Is there any other way?
2. I created a workaround with Spring custom event, listeners and applciation publishers, but nothing seems to work.

I guess what I am looking for is a `Callable<T>` implementation that I can invoke and run on fixed rate and delay.